# Error passing values from function to a controller as an object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, thephpleague

I have the following code:

```
        $storedToken = getStoredToken();

        /**
         * Verify if the stored token has expired.
         */
        if ($storedToken->hasExpired()) {

            /**
             * If the stored token has expired, then you request a new one.
             */
            $newToken = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
                'refresh_token' => $storedToken->getRefreshToken()
```

In my db I have the following fields:

- token
- refreshtoken
- expires

I tried:

```
public function StoredToken(){
    $user = Auth::user(); //data is on users table.
    return $refreshtoken = $user->melirefreshtoken; //eg.

}
```

But with no success. I cannot find the way to create a function to create an object passing all the information.

Right now I received error:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\getStoredToken()

any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide any error code or ar better explanation about where your problem is? You say that "I cannot find the way to create a function to create an object passing all the information"... where? If you need help describing the problem, check this guide: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem seems to be this line:

```
$storedToken = getStoredToken();
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you are trying to call a function from another function (from the same class).. add this:

```
$storedToken = $this->getStoredToken();
//             ^^^^^^^
```